# How to solve linear combination of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

If A, B and C are rectangular matrices of same shape. x and y are two scalars.
And if, xA + yB = C.
How to find x and y?
I know how to do this when A, B and C are vectors. But not sure about matrices.

Comment: "*I know how to do this when $A,B$ and $C$ are vectors. But not sure about matrices*"  You do it in exactly the same way.  There is a direct correlation between for instance finding $x,y$ such that $x\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_4\\a_5&a_6\end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix}b_1&b_2\\b_3&b_4\\b_5&b_6\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}c_1&c_2\\c_3&c_4\\c_5&c_6\end{bmatrix}$ and finding $x,y$ such that $x\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\\a_5\\a_6\end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\\b_4\\b_5\\b_6\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\\c_4\\c_5\\c_6\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $n\times m$ matrices, the matrix equation $xA+yB=C$ is equivalent to a system of $n\cdot m$ linear equations
$$
a_{ij} x + b_{ij} y = c_{ij}
$$
for $i=1,\dots,n$ and $j=1,\dots, m$.

That's the same situation as if $A$, $B$ and $C$ would have been column vectors with $n\cdot m$ entries each.